# Как сделать чтобы мой код работал и в фоновом режиме?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, клавиатура

Есть такой код,

https://gist.github.com/newpander/c8c83f586c9f58a3228dec65c07acd5b
(**код только в такой форме ибо `не влезает`**).

Мой код работает пока выбрано его окно, при выборе другого любого окна код перестает что-либо отображать. 
Нужно чтобы код отображал все и в фоновом режиме, т.е. и когда окно не активное.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    ...

keymap = {}
for key, value in vars(Qt).items():
    if isinstance(value, Qt.Key):
        keymap[value] = key.partition('_')[2]

modmap = {
    Qt.ControlModifier: keymap[Qt.Key_Control],
    Qt.AltModifier: keymap[Qt.Key_Alt],
    Qt.ShiftModifier: keymap[Qt.Key_Shift],
    Qt.MetaModifier: keymap[Qt.Key_Meta],
    Qt.GroupSwitchModifier: keymap[Qt.Key_AltGr],
    Qt.KeypadModifier: keymap[Qt.Key_NumLock],
}


class Example(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.prev_key = []

        self.key_by_time = dict()

    def mousePressEvent(self, ev):
        if ev.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.label.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.label, ]
        elif ev.button() == Qt.RightButton:
            self.rightbuttonmouse.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.rightbuttonmouse, ]
        elif ev.button() == Qt.MiddleButton:
            self.middlebuttonmouse.setStyleSheet("background-color: red; color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.middlebuttonmouse, ]
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, ev):
        if ev.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.label.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.label, ]
        elif ev.button() == Qt.RightButton:
            self.rightbuttonmouse.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.rightbuttonmouse, ]
        elif ev.button() == Qt.MiddleButton:
            self.middlebuttonmouse.setStyleSheet("background-color: ;")
            self.prev_key = [self.middlebuttonmouse, ]

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):

        _key, _keys = self.keyevent_to_string(event)


        key = event.key()
        if not event.isAutoRepeat() and key not in self.key_by_time:
            self.key_by_time[key] = time.perf_counter()
        if self.prev_key:
            for k in self.prev_key:
                k.setStyleSheet("")

        if _keys[0] == 'Control' and key == Qt.Key_W:
            self.W.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.Ctrl.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.Ctrl, self.W]

        elif _keys[0] == 'Alt' and key == Qt.Key_W:
            self.W.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.Alt.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.Alt, self.W]

        elif _keys[0] == 'Shift' and key == Qt.Key_W:
            self.W.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.ShifL.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.ShifL, self.W]

        elif _keys[0] == 'Shift' and key == Qt.Key_Alt:
            self.Alt.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.ShifL.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.ShifL, self.Alt]

        elif key == Qt.Key_W:
            self.W.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.W, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_A:
            self.A.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.A, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_S:
            self.S.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.S, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_D:
            self.D.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.D, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_Space:
            self.space.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.D, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_Escape:
            self.esc.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.esc, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_Tab:
            self.Tab.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.Tab, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_Backspace:
            self.Backspace.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.Backspace, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_Enter:
            self.Enter.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.Enter, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_Return:
            self.Enter.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.Enter, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_QuoteLeft:
            self.tild.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.tild, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_Delete:
            self.dlt.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.dlt, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_Shift:
            self.ShifL.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.ShiftR.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.ShifL, self.ShiftR]

        elif key == Qt.Key_Control:
            self.Ctrl.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.Ctrl, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_Alt:
            self.Alt.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.Alt, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_Meta:
            self.Win.setStyleSheet(" color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.Win, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_Q:
            self.Q.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.Q, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_E:
            self.E.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.E, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_T:
            self.T.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.T, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_R:
            self.R.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.R, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_Y:
            self.Y.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.Y, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_U:
            self.U.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.U, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_I:
            self.I.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.I, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_O:
            self.O.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.O, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_P:
            self.P.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.P, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_F:
            self.F.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.F, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_G:
            self.G.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.G, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_H:
            self.H.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.H, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_J:
            self.J.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.J, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_K:
            self.K.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.K, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_L:
            self.L.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.L, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_Z:
            self.Z.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.Z, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_X:
            self.X.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.X, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_C:
            self.C.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.C, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_V:
            self.V.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.V, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_B:
            self.B.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.B, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_N:
            self.N.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.N, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_M:
            self.M.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.M, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_F1:
            self.f1.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.f1, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_F2:
            self.f2.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.f2, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_F3:
            self.f3.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.f3, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_F4:
            self.f4.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.f4, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_F5:
            self.f5.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.f5, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_F6:
            self.f6.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.f6, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_F7:
            self.f7.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.f7, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_F8:
            self.f8.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.f8, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_F9:
            self.f9.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.f9, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_F10:
            self.f10.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.f10, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_F11:
            self.f11.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.f11, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_F12:
            self.f12.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.f12, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_1:
            self.n1.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.n1,]

        elif key == Qt.Key_2:
            self.n2.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.n2, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_3:
            self.n3.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.n3, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_4:
            self.n4.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.n4, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_5:
            self.n5.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.n5, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_6:
            self.n6.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.n6, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_7:
            self.n7.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.n7, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_8:
            self.n8.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.n8, ]


        elif key == Qt.Key_9:
            self.n9.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.n9, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_0:
            self.n0.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.n0, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_CapsLock:
            self.CapsLock.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.CapsLock, ]
        elif key == Qt.Key_Apostrophe:
            self.quatmark.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.quatmark, ]
        elif key == Qt.Key_Backslash:
            self.revslash.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.revslash, ]
        elif key == Qt.Key_Up:
            self.up.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.up, ]
        elif key == Qt.Key_Down:
            self.down.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.down, ]
        elif key == Qt.Key_Right:
            self.right.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.right, ]
        elif key == Qt.Key_Left:
            self.left.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.left, ]
        elif key == Qt.Key_BracketLeft:
            self.curlybrace1.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.curlybrace1, ]
        elif key == Qt.Key_BracketRight:
            self.curlybrace2.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.curlybrace2, ]
        elif key == Qt.Key_Comma:
            self.rig.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.rig, ]
        elif key == Qt.Key_Period:
            self.lef.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.lef, ]
        elif key == Qt.Key_Slash:
            self.questmark.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.questmark, ]
        elif key == Qt.Key_Minus:
            self.dash.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.dash, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_Semicolon:
            self.colon.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.colon, ]
        elif key == Qt.Key_Equal:
            self.plus.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.plus, ]
    def keyevent_to_string(self, event):
        sequence = []
        for modifier, text in modmap.items():
            if event.modifiers() & modifier:
                sequence.append(text)
        key = keymap.get(event.key(), event.text())
        if key not in sequence:
            sequence.append(key)
        return '+'.join(sequence), sequence

    def keyReleaseEvent(self, event):

        _key, _keys = self.keyevent_to_string(event)

        key = event.key()



        if self.prev_key:
            for k in self.prev_key:
                k.setStyleSheet("")

        if _keys[0] == 'Control' and key == Qt.Key_W:
            self.W.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.Ctrl.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.Ctrl, self.W]
            # ...
        elif _keys[0] == 'Alt' and key == Qt.Key_W:
            self.W.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.Alt.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.Alt, self.W]

        elif key == Qt.Key_BracketRight:
            self.curlybrace2.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.curlybrace2, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_Semicolon:
            self.colon.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.colon, ]
        elif key == Qt.Key_BracketLeft:
            self.curlybrace1.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.curlybrace1, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_BracketLeft:
            self.curlybrace1.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.curlybrace1, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_Space:
            self.space.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.space, ]
        elif key == Qt.Key_BraceLeft:
            self.curlybrace1.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.curlybrace1, ]
        elif _keys[0] == 'Shift' and key == Qt.Key_W:
            self.W.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.ShifL.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.ShifL, self.W]


        elif _keys[0] == 'Shift' and key == Qt.Key_Alt:
            self.Alt.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.ShifL.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.ShifL, self.Alt]

        elif key == Qt.Key_W:
            self.W.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.W, ]
        elif key == Qt.Key_Comma:
            self.lef.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.lef, ]
        elif key == Qt.Key_Period:
            self.rig.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.rig, ]
        elif key == Qt.Key_Slash:
            self.questmark.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.questmark, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_A:
            self.A.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.A, ]
            if not event.isAutoRepeat() and key in self.key_by_time:
                t = self.key_by_time.pop(key)
                self.time_right.setText(f'Кнопка {key!r} была нажата {time.perf_counter() - t:.2f} секунд')



        elif key == Qt.Key_S:
            self.S.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.S, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_D:
            self.D.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.D, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_Escape:
            self.esc.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.esc, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_Tab:
            self.Tab.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.Tab, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_Backspace:
            self.Backspace.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.Backspace, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_Enter:
            self.Enter.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.Enter, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_Return:
            self.Enter.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.Enter, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_QuoteLeft:
            self.tild.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.tild, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_Delete:
            self.dlt.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.dlt, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_Shift:
            self.ShifL.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.ShiftR.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.ShifL, self.ShiftR]

        elif key == Qt.Key_Control:
            self.Ctrl.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.Ctrl, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_Alt:
            self.Alt.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.Alt, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_Meta:
            self.Win.setStyleSheet(" color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.Win, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_Q:
            self.Q.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.Q, ]
        elif key == Qt.Key_E:
            self.E.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.E, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_T:
            self.T.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.T, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_R:
            self.R.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.R, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_Y:
            self.Y.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.Y, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_U:
            self.U.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.U, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_I:
            self.I.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.I, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_O:
            self.O.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.O, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_P:
            self.P.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.P, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_F:
            self.F.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.F, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_G:
            self.G.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.G, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_H:
            self.H.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.H, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_J:
            self.J.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.J, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_K:
            self.K.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.K, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_L:
            self.L.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.L, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_Z:
            self.Z.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.Z, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_X:
            self.X.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.X, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_C:
            self.C.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.C, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_V:
            self.V.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.V, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_B:
            self.B.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.B, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_N:
            self.N.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.N, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_M:
            self.M.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.M, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_F1:
            self.f1.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.f1, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_F2:
            self.f2.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.f2, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_F3:
            self.f3.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.f3, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_F4:
            self.f4.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.f4, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_F5:
            self.f5.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.f5, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_F6:
            self.f6.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.f6, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_F7:
            self.f7.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.f7, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_F8:
            self.f8.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.f8, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_F9:
            self.f9.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.f9, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_F10:
            self.f10.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.f10, ]
        elif key == Qt.Key_F11:
            self.f11.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.f11, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_F12:
            self.f12.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.f12, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_1:
            self.n1.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.n1, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_2:
            self.n2.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.n2, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_3:
            self.n3.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.n3, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_4:
            self.n4.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.n4, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_5:
            self.n5.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.n5, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_6:
            self.n6.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.n6, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_7:
            self.n7.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.n7, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_8:
            self.n8.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.n8, ]


        elif key == Qt.Key_9:
            self.n9.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.n9, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_0:
            self.n0.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.n0, ]

        elif key == Qt.Key_CapsLock:
            self.CapsLock.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.CapsLock, ]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Example()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

но при переходе на другое окно он ничего не отображает.

Мой код работает пока выбрано его окно, при выборе другого любого окна код перестает что-либо отображать. Нужно чтобы код отображал все и в фоновом режиме

Comment: Непонятно что вы хотите, объясните в чем вы видите проблему

Comment: @gil9red, мой код работает пока выбрано его окно, при выборе другого любого окна код перестает что-либо отображать. Нужно чтобы код отображал все и в фоновом режиме

Comment: А... боюсь придется переделывать весь код обработки кнопок. Сейчас, у вас при получении событий срабатывает код, т.к. виджет обрабатывает свои события. А чтобы глобально следить нужно другое. Попробуйте модуль `keyboard`: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/c7a58f1078de1a66e0bdd9c9f030b35456fb5613/pyautogui__keyboard__examples/keyboard_hook.py

Comment: [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Qt может получить доступ к событиям клавиатуры,
> только если любое из его окон верхнего уровня имеет фокус клавиатуры. 
> `Если окно свернуто или другое окно сфокусировано, вы` **`не будете`** `получать события клавиатуры`.

Единственное решение - использовать внешнюю библиотеку, но у них есть ограничения
в зависимости от используемой ОС.
Eсть разные решения, вам может понадобиться посмотреть в
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyboard/    или
https://pypi.org/project/pynput/          .

Обратите внимание:

- ваш пример сокращен до минимального.
  Для наблюдения происходящего  используйте клавишу `A` .
- форма перенесена в отдельный модуль **keyboard_ui.py**.
- использовал библиотеку **`keyboard`**`, если окно не активное`  !!!

То что вы хотите, может выглядеть примерно так:

```
import time
import keyboard                                          # pip install keyboard
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from keyboard_ui import Ui_MainWindow


keymap = {}
for key, value in vars(Qt).items():
    if isinstance(value, Qt.Key):
        keymap[value] = key.partition('_')[2]

modmap = {
    Qt.ControlModifier: keymap[Qt.Key_Control],
    Qt.AltModifier: keymap[Qt.Key_Alt],
    Qt.ShiftModifier: keymap[Qt.Key_Shift],
    Qt.MetaModifier: keymap[Qt.Key_Meta],
    Qt.GroupSwitchModifier: keymap[Qt.Key_AltGr],
    Qt.KeypadModifier: keymap[Qt.Key_NumLock],
}


class Example(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.prev_key = []
        self.key_by_time = dict()        

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.qwindowIsActive = True
        self.hook = None
        QTimer.singleShot(0, self.on_qwindow)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.label.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.label, ]
        # ...
        
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.label.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.label, ]
        # ...

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        _key, _keys = self.keyevent_to_string(event)
        key = event.key()
        if not event.isAutoRepeat() and key not in self.key_by_time:
            self.key_by_time[key] = time.perf_counter()
        if self.prev_key:
            for k in self.prev_key:
                k.setStyleSheet("")
                
        if _keys[0] == 'Control' and key == Qt.Key_A:
            self.A.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.Ctrl.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.Ctrl, self.A]
        elif _keys[0] == 'Alt' and key == Qt.Key_A:
            self.A.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.Alt.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.Alt, self.A]
        elif _keys[0] == 'Shift' and key == Qt.Key_A:
            self.A.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.ShifL.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.ShifL, self.A]
        elif key == Qt.Key_A:
            self.A.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.A, ]        
        # ...

    def keyReleaseEvent(self, event):
        _key, _keys = self.keyevent_to_string(event)
        key = event.key()
        if self.prev_key:
            for k in self.prev_key:
                k.setStyleSheet("")

        if _keys[0] == 'Control' and key == Qt.Key_A:
            self.A.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.Ctrl.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.Ctrl, self.A]
        elif _keys[0] == 'Alt' and key == Qt.Key_A:
            self.A.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.Alt.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.Alt, self.A]
        elif _keys[0] == 'Shift' and key == Qt.Key_A:
            self.A.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.ShifL.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.ShifL, self.A]
        elif key == Qt.Key_A:
            self.A.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.A, ]
            if not event.isAutoRepeat() and key in self.key_by_time:
                t = self.key_by_time.pop(key)
                self.time_right.setText(f'Кнопка {key!r} была нажата {time.perf_counter() - t:.2f} секунд')
        # ...
            
    def keyevent_to_string(self, event):
        sequence = []
        for modifier, text in modmap.items():
            if event.modifiers() & modifier:
                sequence.append(text)
        key = keymap.get(event.key(), event.text())
        if key not in sequence:
            sequence.append(key)
        return '+'.join(sequence), sequence

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    def on_qwindow(self):        
        self.qwindow = self.windowHandle()
        self.qwindow.activeChanged.connect(self.handle_activeChanged)

    def handle_activeChanged(self):
        print("окно активное (isActive)? {}".format(self.qwindow.isActive()))               # !!!
        if self.qwindow.isActive():
            self.qwindowIsActive = True
        else:
            self.qwindowIsActive = False
        self.setGrabbing()    
        
    def setGrabbing(self): 
        if not self.qwindowIsActive:                                  # если окно не активное 
            self.hook = keyboard.hook(self.keyboardEventReceived)            
        else:
            if self.hook:
                keyboard.unhook(self.hook)
        
    def keyboardEventReceived(self, event):
        print(f"keyboardEventReceived: event_type -> {event.event_type}, event.name -> {event.name}")
        
        if event.event_type == 'down':
            if event.name in ['A', 'a']:
                print('A Press')
                self.A.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
        # ...
                
        if event.event_type == 'up':
            if event.name in ['A', 'a']:
                print('A Release')   
                self.A.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
        # ...
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Example()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]